# Failed unmounting Mount unit for nvidia support in snappy

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04

I got an updated driver through the software updater, but when I rebooted I suddenly couldn't login to my system anymore. I used `Ctrl + Alt + F1` to try and purge my nvidia drivers, but I got the following message:

```
Job for var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount failed. See "systemctl status var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I used `journalctl -xe` and found the following error:

```
jun 04 00:26:17 Unity-X550JF systemd[1]: Failed unmounting Mount unit for nvidia support in snappy.
```

So long story short: The updated driver borked my system and I can't uninstall it in order to try to fix it. This leaves with a broken system where I can't login and attempting to login just throws me back to the login screen..

Does someone know what I can do this fix this? I can't use this now I really really need to get work done.

Comment: MAy i point you to the solution I provided [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/783093/cannot-remove-nvidia-opencl-icd-367). This all seems to come from a patch which hit upstream to soon and got packaged and pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem after upgrading. Waiting for response. I'm nearly used to that the system will go down every time after upgrading...

I temporarily solved it by stopping lightdm and reinstalling NVIDIA driver:

systemctl stop lightdm.service

purge nvidia (I have nvidia-364 installed)

install nvidia-367