# I have a broken nvidia-361 package

Tags: 16.04, apt, nvidia, 16.10

After an update from 16.04 to 16.10 a transitional package for nvidia-361 driver start giving an error.

This is the message (some data is translated to EN from BG):

```
Preparation for the unpacking of nvidia-352_361.45.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount: Unit var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount not loaded.
dpkg: warning: under process old pre-removal script returned error status out of 5

dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9wUQ2T/8-nvidia-352_361.45.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 no script in the new version of the package - I surrender (or something like it)
Failed to get unit file state for var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount: No such file or directory
var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Error in the process:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9wUQ2T/8-nvidia-352_361.45.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT:
Seems i forgot some data (added in the prevous text):

```
Preparation for the unpacking of nvidia-352_361.45.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount: Unit var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount not loaded.
dpkg: warning: under process old pre-removal script returned error status out of 5
```

Comment: `/surrender/give up/`? Use `env lang=C somecommand` to get error messages in english.

Comment: env lang=C didn't help. SOme of the messages were still in BG.
 I use the command: "sudo env lang=C apt full-upgrade"

Answer (score 0):

I would trash that package and start over. I'm not sure where you obtained it, but it sounds like the deb package is corrupt as it's failing to unpack.  You could try downloading the deb package manually from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/nvidia-352) and installing it manually with gdebi using the command `gdebi nvidia-352_361.45.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb` or with `aptitude` using the command `aptitude install nvidia-352_361.45.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb`

`gdebi`

```
   lets you install local deb packages resolving and installing its
   dependencies. apt does the  same,  but  only  for  remote  (http,  ftp)
   located packages.
```

Provided you manage to obtain an uncorrupted package either of these should do the trick.

EDIT: There doesn't seem to be much in this package other than a Copyright notice containing a discussion regarding redistributing the NVIDIA graphics driver. That being the case you might wish to install [this package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/nvidia-367) for your version and architecture instead.

Sources:

`man gdebi`

https://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=yakkety&arch=amd64&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia

Comment: @Videonauth Please check the content of the package the OP is referring to. There's no binary driver in it.

Comment: O.k. my bad, sorry for this.

Comment: @Videonauth No worries! ;-)

Comment: I would trash the package too. I did several purges of nvidia driver, this problem always pop-up.
I had downloaded the nvidia-352_361.45.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb.
then use gdebi nvidia-352_361.45.11-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb.
Still the same error.

Comment: Try the nvidia-367 package linked near the bottom of my answer (in the EDIT section) The package you are attempting to install has no driver in it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the problem was in missing or corrupt var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount file, after a replace everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue. Put a dummy `sudo touch /lib/systemd/system/var-lib-snapd-lib-gl.mount` (the file that wasn't available) then `sudo apt purge nvidia*`. Several reboots etc.

The full answer is [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783093/installing-nvidia-opencl-icd-367-breaks-the-package-manager)

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. So what your saying is that your question is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/783093/installing-nvidia-opencl-icd-367-breaks-the-package-manager. Thank you for bringing that yo our attention.